# how to register an event handler for the capture phase in React-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, capture

By default event of element are in the `bubbling` phase. in javascript if we going to convert it to capture, we have the following way:

1- when the value of useCapture is set to true, the event uses the capturing propagation(in third argument):

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
```

2- jQuery only uses event bubbling.

now my main question is that although we make the evnet inline `<div onclick= {} />` , how to change bubbling phase to capturing in React?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite straightforward.

For event bubbling

```
<div onClick={() => { alert('Bubbling');}} >
This will result into event bubbling
</div>
```

For event capturing

```
<div onClickCapture={() => { alert('Capturing');}} >
This will result into event capturing
</div>
```

You can also refer to the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)

Answer (score 1):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      //  write event handling logic here
    };
    // this will detect all clicks events
    document.addEventListener("click", handler, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
    // if we had a dependency, cleanup would be called before rerendering
  }, []);
```

assume that you have a button element in jsx

```
 <Button
    onClick={handleClick}
  >
    Test Button
  </Button>
```

when a user clicks on this button since we added `true` option for the registered event inside the `useEffect`, the browser will look at the top parent element which is the `document`, and starting from the top it will check if any parent has a click handler if it does it calls that first.

I explained in details here: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/74858576#74858576)